# Running multpe containers without composer?

Tags: docker, nginx

Hey all I have three containers that I am currently running in compose

```
version: '2'

services:

  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: deploy-1w/web.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    links:
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/source/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - 'DEBUG=true'
      - 'DOCKER_COMPOSE_MODE=true'
      - 'APP_ENV=local'

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: deploy-1w/nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web
    env_file:
      - .env
    links:
      - web:web
    environment:
      - "BACKEND_ADDR=web:9000"
      - 'DOCKER_COMPOSE_MODE=true'
      - 'APP_ENV=local'


  redis:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: deploy-1w/cache.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redisdata:/data
```

I am trying to run these without using compose (more for debugging purposes and understanding of what composer is actually DOING more than anything) but due to the links etc i am not able to get them running (nginx is using proxy pass and looking for an upstream of `web`)

Here's the Dockerfile for `web`

```
FROM python:2-onbuild

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN cp -rf /usr/src/app/src/* /usr/src/app/

# build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git-core rubygems ruby-dev gettext nano  \
    && wget nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz                 \
    && tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v6.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get install nodejs-legacy -y                                              \
    && gem install sass compass                                                   \
    && npm install -g grunt-cli bower

# Bad command?
#RUN npm install -g

RUN npm install grunt@0.4.5 -g --save-dev                                         \
    && npm install                                                                \
    && bower install --allow-root

RUN grunt buildcss                                                                \
    && grunt buildjs --force


# Add the local settings file
COPY ./deploy-1w/config/local_settings.py /usr/src/app/source/source/local_settings.py


# copy the bootstrap script
COPY ./deploy-1w/web-bootstrap.sh  /usr/local/bin/web-bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod 775 /usr/local/bin/web-bootstrap.sh


WORKDIR /usr/src/app/source

# run bootstrap script
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/web-bootstrap.sh"]
```

Nginx

```
FROM tutum/nginx

# backend web address
ENV BACKEND_ADDR 0.0.0.0:0


# build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext


# copy config template
COPY ./deploy-1w/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template


# copy static file to use as a health check
COPY ./deploy-1w/config/nginx-health-check /var/www/html/public/health-check


# copy the bootstrap script
COPY ./deploy-1w/nginx-bootstrap.sh  /usr/local/bin/nginx-bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod 775 /usr/local/bin/nginx-bootstrap.sh


# run bootstrap script
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/nginx-bootstrap.sh"]
```

and Redis

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV REDIS_MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION 4.0
ENV REDIS_VERSION 4.0.10
ENV REDIS_TARBALL_SHA1 d2738d9b93a3220eecc83e89a7c28593b58e4909
ENV BACKEND_ADDR 0.0.0.0:0

RUN apt-get -q update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
    build-essential \
    curl && \
  curl -O http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-$REDIS_VERSION.tar.gz && \
  [ $(shasum redis-$REDIS_VERSION.tar.gz | awk '{ print $1 }') = $REDIS_TARBALL_SHA1 ] && \
  tar zxf redis-$REDIS_VERSION.tar.gz && \
  cd redis-$REDIS_VERSION && \
  make -j$(nproc) && \
  cd src && \
  cp \
    redis-benchmark \
    redis-check-aof \
    redis-check-rdb \
    redis-cli \
    redis-sentinel \
    redis-server \
    /usr/local/bin && \
  cd ../.. && \
  rm -rf redis-$REDIS_VERSION redis-$REDIS_VERSION.tar.gz /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
  apt-get -qy purge build-essential curl && \
  apt-get -qy clean autoclean autoremove && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}/

COPY ./deploy-1w/config/redis.conf /etc/redis.conf

VOLUME /var/lib/redis

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/redis-server", "/etc/redis.conf"]
```

I am literally trying to do what i'm doing in composer... without composer...

What i'm doing is this, and it's failing

```
docker build -t redis-test -f deploy-1w/cache.dockerfile .
docker build -t nginx-test -f deploy-1w/nginx.dockerfile .
docker build -t web-test -f deploy-1w/web.dockerfile .

docker network create test-network

docker run -d -it -p --network test-network '6379:6379' redis-test
docker run -d -it -p --network test-network '9000:9000' --link $(docker ps -a | grep redis-test |awk '{print$1}') web-test 
docker run -d -it -p --network test-network '80:80' -e 'BACKEND_ADDR=web:9000' --link $(docker ps -a | grep web-test |awk '{print$1}') nginx-test
```

The above give me an error...

```
bash-4.4$ docker logs bc28bcd28653
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35
```

Here's the pertinent part of the nginx conf

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://${BACKEND_ADDR};    <-- Line 35
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: first, you should use the last docker-compose version because link it's deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to have so many issues with docker and nginx because I didn't understand everything very well.
So here is my recommendation:

**Quick fix** :

Add

```
nginx:
    restart: always
    ....
    depends_on:
        - web
```

**Explanation :**

Nginx with upstream can be useful but if the upstream doesn't exist, then nginx will never start.
And in the `docker` case, you have to say that web should run before nginx using `depends_on` parameter.

But after upgrading my stack to docker swarm, I discovered that `depends_on` can't be used anymore across multiple instances 
for a reason I don't remember.

So I wanted to start nginx even if my web server is not running and the easy way to do it is to use variable
in nginx like this :

```
      set $server_1 web;
      proxy_pass http://$server_1:8080;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header HOST $host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

I definitly advise you to use the last docker-compose version because you have so much better feature.
Also, using link is quite deprecated, I recommend you to create an internal network using `docker network` command.
It's very useful to add or remove an instance to it and you save time and maintainability.

**Running multiple containers without composer**

You need to use `docker run` command for each container

```
docker run -d --name web -p 9000:9000 ....
docker run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 ....
```

Comment: So in the above, after running the container, after running web nginx will usurp web and be visible I take it? I am trying to steer clear of docker compose since we use Nomad in our envs

Comment: Yeah exactly, if he is not launched, it will not be linked. If you run inside of a network, it easier because you don't need to restart the instance